# How can I put only the conversations list in it's own scroll view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a screenshot for example when there is 3 conversations :
And I have 4 buttons. Add/Remove item and save/load

[image: conversations]

And now for example when there are 100 conversations :
Now the 4 buttons pushed down and I need to scroll down to see the buttons :

[image: conversations]

What I want to do is somehow to make a scroll view only the the conversations.
So when there are too many conversations instead that the inspector will have scrollers the conversations will have it's own scroll view. So maximum the 4 buttons can get to the bottom but not out of the screen view.

So the conversations scroll view can get size much large on the vertical until the button get to the bottom after that just keep the conversations in the scroll view.

This is the editor script for the inspector :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger conversationtrigger;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversationtrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        GUILayout.Space(20);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Add new conversation"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.conversations.Add(new Conversation());
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Remove conversation"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.conversations.RemoveAt(conversationtrigger.conversations.Count - 1);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(100);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationtrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationtrigger.LoadConversations();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good fekking luck man. IMGui is a nightmare to work with and scrollable areas are the one thing I've never messed with and I don't even want to think about it. But take a look at [`GUILayout.BeginScrollView`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.BeginScrollView.html)

Comment: @Draco18s What else can I use for visual graphics like the inspector ? If not using IMGui what other alternatives there are ?

Comment: Editor stuff is always IMGui, there aren't other options. But that doesn't make IMGui any less painful to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView()

Here's the documentation on it: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView.html

You'd just need to add three lines.

```
private Vector2 scrollPos; // add this line above the following line
private ConversationTrigger conversationtrigger;
...
scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250)); // add
DrawDefaultInspector(); // add the above and below lines around this existing line
EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView(); // add
```

The 250 can be changed to whatever you want the max height to be.

Comment: This is almost working perfect. The only thing is if for example I'm changing the list size from 100 to 2 then the scroll view is gone and that's fine but then it's leaving a big empty space between the conversations and the buttons.

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to use the combination of `GUILayout.MinHeight()` and `GUILayout.MaxHeight()` and possibly `GUILayout.ExpandHeight(true)` to achieve dynamic height... but after experimenting for a while I couldn't find a combination that worked. So maybe it's not supported for that particular GUILayout element.